# How do I fix my colour palette in android studio?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am currently doing a project where people can draw in two sections of the same screen. The main  problem right now is that when I draw something and then decide to change to a different colour everything changes to the same colour I choose.

This is the code currently:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pathList1.size(); i++) {
            int colorIndex = i % colorList1.size(); // select a color from the colorList based on i index
            paint_brush.setColor(colorList1.get(colorIndex));
            canvas.drawPath(pathList1.get(i), paint_brush);
        }
        invalidate();
    }
```

Can someone help me out? I'm sure it's something simple I am missing but don't know what.

I've tried this from ChatGPT:

```
private int lastColorIndex = -1; // initialize with an invalid index

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pathList1.size(); i++) {
        int colorIndex = (lastColorIndex + 1) % colorList1.size(); // select a color from the colorList that is different from the last color
        paint_brush.setColor(colorList1.get(colorIndex));
        canvas.drawPath(pathList1.get(i), paint_brush);
        lastColorIndex = colorIndex; // update the last color index
    }
}
```

But it just made it worse somehow? The colours wouldn't change at all.

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste your time with code from ChatGPT. It's not advanced enough for this kind of thing yet, so it's just eating up your time with code that will have subtle bugs.

You need to store not just Paths, but also the color of those Paths.

So create a wrapper class:

```
class DrawnPath {
    final Path path;
    final int colorIndex;

    DrawnPath(Path path, int colorIndex) {
        this.path = path;
        this.colorIndex = colorIndex;
    }
}
```

Change your `pathList1` (and I assume there's also a `pathList2`) into a `List<DrawnPath>` instead of a `List<Path>`. When the user draws a new path, put it in an instance of this wrapper class using the current color index.

```
//some member variable:
private int currentColorIndex1; // for user number 1

// when user number 1 touches down to begin drawing:
currentColorIndex1 = (currentColorIndex1 + 1) % colorList1.size();
```

When you draw it, use the color wrapped with each path. And use a for-each loop for simplicity.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (DrawnPath drawnPath : pathList1) {
        paint_brush.setColor(colorList1.get(drawnPath.colorIndex));
        canvas.drawPath(drawnPath.path, paint_brush);
    }
    invalidate();
}
```